# jqGrid: Additional Edit Parameters not being posted to server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm using the `Lib.Web.MVC` helper so my initial jqGrid JS is generated by that object.  After the call to @grid.GetJavaScript, I then issue a separate call to modify the `editData` collection as specified below.  Here is the effective JS that I'm using.  The values of `AreaId` and `AreaItemId` don't ever get submitted to the controller action.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#GetAreaItemDetails').jqGrid({
        colNames: ['Code', 'Name', 'Description', 'Has Addl Comments'],
        colModel: [
            { editable: true, editoptions: { "maxlength": 16 }, editrules: { required: true },
                name: 'AreaItemDetailCode'
            },
            { editable: true, editoptions: { "maxlength": 32 }, editrules: { required: true },
                name: 'AreaItemDetailName'
            },
            { editable: true, editoptions: { "maxlength": 128 }, editrules: { required: true },
                name: 'AreaItemDetailDescription'
            },
            { editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editrules: { required: true },
                name: 'HasAdditionalComments'
            }],
        caption: 'Area Item Details',
        url: '/Admin/GetAreaItemDetails',
        datatype: 'json',
        footerrow: true,
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: 'Id', subgrid: { repeatitems: false} },
        mtype: 'POST',
        pager: '#GetAreaItemDetailsPager',
        prmNames: { npage: 'npage' },
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        rowNum: 10,
        sortname: 'AreaItemDetailId',
        viewrecords: true,
        height: '100%'
    }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#GetAreaItemDetailsPager',
        { search: false },
        { height: 175, url: '/Admin/UpdateAreaItemDetail', width: 400, recreateForm: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true
        },
        { height: 175, url: '/Admin/InsertAreaItemDetail', width: 400, recreateForm: true,
            closeAfterAdd: true
        });

    $("#GetAreaItemDetails").jqGrid('navGrid', '#GetAreaItemDetailsPager',
        {/*navGrid options*/},
        {
            editData: {
                AreaItemId: function () {
                    return $('#ddlAreaItems').val();
                },
                AreaId: function () {
                    return $('#ddlAreas').val();
                }
            }
        },
        {
            editData: {
                AreaItemId: function () {
                    return $('#ddlAreaItems').val();
                },
                AreaId: function () {
                    return $('#ddlAreas').val();
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the reason of your problem are **two calls** of `navGrid` which you do instead of one. The  [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) method creates the navigator bar. You can create only *one* navigator bar in the grid.

How you can see from [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.3/js/grid.formedit.js#L1729) of code of `navGrid` the function test existence of `nav` property which will be crated by the method (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.3/js/grid.formedit.js#L1976) which just assign `this.nav = true;`). So the code

```
if(this.nav) {return;}
```

will be used just **to skip** the second execution of the method.

So to solve your problem you should just combine two calls in one:

```
...
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#GetAreaItemDetailsPager',
    { search: false },
    { height: 175, url: '/Admin/UpdateAreaItemDetail', width: 400, recreateForm: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        editData: {
            AreaItemId: function () {
                return $('#ddlAreaItems').val();
            },
            AreaId: function () {
                return $('#ddlAreas').val();
            }
        }
    },
    { height: 175, url: '/Admin/InsertAreaItemDetail', width: 400, recreateForm: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        editData: {
            AreaItemId: function () {
                return $('#ddlAreaItems').val();
            },
            AreaId: function () {
                return $('#ddlAreas').val();
            }
        }
    });
```

You can reduce the code if you would set common Add and Edit settings as default settings (on the page) for form editing

```
$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
    height: 175,
    url: '/Admin/InsertAreaItemDetail',
    width: 400,
    recreateForm: true,
    closeAfterAdd: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    editData: {
        AreaItemId: function () {
            return $('#ddlAreaItems').val();
        },
        AreaId: function () {
            return $('#ddlAreas').val();
        }
    }
});
```

*before* calling of `navGrid`. In the case the call itself can be reduced to

```
...
}).jqGrid('navGrid', '#GetAreaItemDetailsPager', { search: false });
```

Comment: Sorry about the code formatting.  I don't know how to do that properly on SO, and I am forced to use IE8 at work. :)  The Lib.Web.Mvc helper is used to generate the original JS for the grid, and the ExtraData parameter cannot be used.  Is there any way to issue a subsequent call to update the navigation properties?

Comment: @LSU.Net: You can use `$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {...}` approach at least to set `editData`. I don't know `Lib.Web.Mvc`, but I suppose that all will work correctly.

Comment: @LSU.Net: By the way [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) is described how you can format the code. In general if you just select the full code fragment and press `{}` button above the editing window 4 blanks will be added in every marked lines. So the code will be already correct formatted.