# How tot take the data from a cell that is not editable in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid and I need to post a value from a cell that is not editable when I do inline editing.

I tried using:

```
 editData: {
   proiect: jQuery("#Id").getCell(jQuery("#Id").getGridParam('selrow'), 'ColName') 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand you correct. In any way `editData` is the property which can be used in case of **form editing** (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties)). If you need to send some additional information to the server `extraparam` or `serializeRowData`. The exact implementation depend on the way in which you use inline editing. For example if you call `editRow` directly inside of `onSelectRow` then you can do the following

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
    var $this = $(this),
        cellValue = $this.jqGrid("getCell", id, 'ColName');

    if (id && id!==lastSel){ 
        $this.jqGrid("restoreRow", lastSel); 
        lastSel = id; 
    }

    $this.jqGrid("editRow", id, {
        keys: true,
        extraparam: {
            proiect: cellValue
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 for inline editing tips. However, when using form editing, is there an alternative solution? The editData approach seems to work with one issue. The value of the selected ColName cell is always false and this should be a string.

Comment: @thedev: you can find the text "I do inline editing" in the text of the question. So the usage of `editData` would be wrong in the case. If you use form editing then [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10901920/315935) could be helpful. Alternatively one can use `serializeEditData` jqGrid callback or `onclickSubmit` callback of form editing editing. `onclickSubmit` can return object with *additional* parameters as properties which will be added to the parameters sent to the server.

Comment: @thedev: See [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L659-L662) and [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L686) to understand what should return [onclickSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) callback.